# Visual Studio 2013 incorrect namespace errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, visual-studio-2013, static-analysis

Visual Studio 2013 keeps reporting namespace reference errors, even while the build is successful:

[image]

Even namespaces/classes in our code cannot be found at times:

[image]

All while our build is still successful.  Sometimes we have to code blind because we know the reference will be fine when building.  It is very frustrating.

Cleaning sometimes helps to get rid of these errors, but mostly they remain and disappear at will it seems.

Comment: I'd actually be worried by the 187 warnings: that is a very very large number. Cleaning that up might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say this happened to me and not even a simple `Show.Dialog()` was recognized and would give me the same errors.

What I did was a reinstall of the IDE Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I am pretty sure this will solve your issue, other than that I cannot explain why such an error would stand up.